# Visual Studio Installer Projects including too many DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I am attempting to use Visual Studio Installer Projects to make an installer for my app.  I am using Visual Studio 2015, and my app is built using WPF and .NET 4.5.

I was following this general tutorial on how to make a Visual Studio Installer Project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0v6hmumCFU

When I include the "primary output" of each of my projects in the installer, it goes out and identifies the dependencies of these projects and includes them as files that need to be in the installer.  I am puzzled, however, because it even seems to be including several standard "system" .NET DLL files, as you can see in this image below:

[image: Image of visual studio installer project]

I tried building it, and then running the installer that it builds, and sure enough it installs all of these "system" DLL files into the install directory.

My understanding is that these DLL files should be on the user's computer already in a standard location once the user has installed .NET 4.5 or later, so my installer shouldn't need to copy over many of these dependencies into the install directory.

So my question is thus:

(1) Why does the Visual Studio Installer Project extension include these dependencies which are obviously part of .NET and should really be located in a standard .NET install location?

(2) Would it be fine to exclude them?

(3) Is there a way to get the VS Installer Project extension to simply not add them?

Comment: These are not .NET Framework assemblies, they are .NETCore reference assemblies.  Probably brought in by one of the libraries you use.   The ancient VS add-in you use doesn't know beans about .NETCore and has no idea that they are not actually dependencies.  WPF is a thousand miles away from .NETCore, you'll want to find a flavor of the library that doesn't attempt to support it.